# Why does Laravel Migrations on Windows migrates the first table but not the others?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

For example, I have three migration tables(e.g. User, Role, Department) that I need to migrate. In laravel, it is as simple as issuing the command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

However, I'm using Windows(cmd/powershell), and every time I issue the migrate command only the first table gets migrated. If I try to re-issue the migrate command I get an error stating the "Users table exists".

Do I have an error in my laravel installation or is this normal?

In order to bypass the above error, I have to rename each table.For example, if I migrated "User", then I need to rename the User table as:

```
"create_users_table_2344747474.sql.bak"
```

The above is necessary for me in order to facilitate the migration of the other tables, in this example "Role" and "Department" as explained above.

Installation Tech specs:
[image]

**Update:** specific error. Description: as you can see below, the "User table" is migrated successfully. I can see it in mysql. However, the other tables are not migrated. Laravel is **Laravel Framework 5.6.13**

[image: error specified]

**Update:** user table migration.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

These other migrations are not "migrated" to the database.

[image]

Comment: may i know full error? when u type php artisan:migrate? print ir here..

Comment: I updated my question and added a picture of the error. As explained in my question, only one table is migrated after issuing the command: php artisan migrate.

Comment: can you post your user migration?

Comment: Post your User table migration

Comment: I posted the user migration table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your version of mysql? as per documentation: If you are running a version of MySQL older than the 5.7.7 release or MariaDB older than the 10.2.2 release, you may need to manually configure the default string length generated by migrations in order for MySQL to create indexes for them. You may configure this by calling the Schema::defaultStringLength method within your AppServiceProvider:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to double check this. I didn't revise the database version. I'm using MariaDB.

Comment: Yes. You were correct. I used Xampp[v3.2.2], and the MariaDB distribution that's bundled with Xampp is 10.1. I custom swapped the MariaDB[10.1] that comes with Xampp[v3.2.2] with a fresh installation of the latest release of MariaDB: [Server version: 10.2.14-MariaDB], and it works normally now.

Answer (score 0):

I ever got the same issue like this.. This is because the email field in user table, but I solved it with adding the length of the data like:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email', 255)->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

then, do `php artisan migrate:refresh`.
if still not working, open your database then delete all the table and migrate it again.. Hope this can help you to solve your issue

Comment: have you clear the all the cache in your project? @FullArray